# Plotly autoscroll rangeselector

Tags: python, svg, plotly, plotly-dash

Trying to automatically scroll the rangeselector with the video.

Any help would be appreciated. Below is some code of what I've tried so far, which renders the original plot's rangeselector only, but no autoscrolling (i.e. subsequent plots).

[image]

Make the gantt chart with range-selector

```
import plotly.figure_factory as ff

def make_timeline(df, current_time=0):
    y = len(df['Task'].unique())
    fig = ff.create_gantt(df, height=y * 15, bar_width=0.2, index_col='Resource', show_colorbar=True, group_tasks=True, title='Tags Timeline')
    fig.update_layout(
        xaxis=dict(
            rangeselector=dict(
            ),
            rangeslider=dict(
                visible=True
            ),
            type="category",
            autorange=False,
            range=(current_time, current_time + 30)
        )
    )
    return fig
```

Main dash app

```
import dash_core_components as dcc

     app.layout = html.Div(

         children=[
             
               dcc.Interval(id="interval-updating-graphs", interval=1000, n_intervals=0),

               html.Div(
                            className="video-outer-container",
                            children=html.Div(
                                className="video-container",
                                children=player.DashPlayer(
                                    id="video-display",
                                    url="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9F5FdcVmLOY",#"http://0.0.0.0:8000/PycharmProjects/dash-maf-viz/data/videos/FILE_MAF_20200302T235220Z_SNL-4512-HD.mp4",#"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9F5FdcVmLOY",
                                    controls=True,
                                    playing=True,
                                    volume=1,
                                    width="100%",
                                    height="100%",
                                    seekTo=26
                                ),
                            ),
                        ),

                html.Div(
                  id="tags-timeline",
                  className="eight columns",
                  children=[
                     dcc.Graph(id='tags-timeline-graph'),
                   ]
                )
            )
```

Thought this callback would autoscroll by redrawing the graph each second with a different starting point. (not included here: I also tried calling maketimeline() every 30 seconds in case of latency, though still not redrawing. )

```
@app.callback(
    [Output('tags-timeline-graph', 'figure')],
    [Input('video-display', 'currentTime')])
def update_timeline(currentTime):
    if currentTime:
        pass
    else:
        currentTime=0
    return make_timeline(df, currentTime)
```